# Connect to Raspberry Pi via Ethernet while connected to Internet via Wifi

Tags: wifi, ethernet, internet-sharing

I have Macbook Air with a USB-to-Ethernet adapter connected to an Ethernet cable that is plugged into the Ethernet port of a Raspberry Pi. When I turn off my Wifi, I can VNC/SSH into the Pi.  However, when Wifi is turned on and connected to the internet, the Pi becomes unreachable through the ethernet connection.

I would like to be able to connect to the Raspberry Pi over the ethernet cable while remaining connected to internet so I can debug python scripts on the Pi and use VNC/SSH into the Pi while having access to the internet on my Macbook Air.

I have tried the following:

- Changing the priority of the network services in System Preferences... Network...Set Service Order...move ethernet to #1 first priority
- turning off the wifi, connecting to the pi, then turning on wifi but the connection drops

My network settings with ethernet plugged into Pi (but not working) and wifi connected to internet are as follows:

Network service order: AX88179 USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet -> RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget -> KYOCERA USB Modem -> SAMSUNG Modem -> Wi-Fi -> Bluetooth PAN -> Thunderbolt Bridge

AX8817 USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet Network Information:

- Configure IPv4: Using DHCP
- IP Address: 169.254.39.77
- Subnet Mask: 255.255.0.0
- Router: (Blank)
- DNS Server: (Blank)
- Search Domains: (Blank)

Wi-Fi: Connected to WifiNetwork with IP Address 172.15.2.123

```
$ping raspberrypi.local
PING raspberrypi.local (169.254.151.48): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
```

My network settings when ethernet connection to Pi is working and Wifi is turned off:

Network service order: AX88179 USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet -> RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget -> KYOCERA USB Modem -> SAMSUNG Modem -> Wi-Fi -> Bluetooth PAN -> Thunderbolt Bridge

AX8817 USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet Network Information:

- Configure IPv4: Using DHCP
- IP Address: 169.254.172.210
- Subnet Mask: 255.255.0.0
- Router: (Blank)
- DNS Server: (Blank)
- Search Domains: (Blank)

Wi-Fi: OFF

```
$ping raspberrypi.local
PING raspberrypi.local (169.254.151.48): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 169.254.151.48: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.387 ms
64 bytes from 169.254.151.48: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.734 ms
64 bytes from 169.254.151.48: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.761 ms
```

Any advice would be most welcome! Thank you.

Comment: There seems to be two questions here - 1) Ethernet stops working when connected to WiFi Network and 2) Setting up Internet Sharing.    Please edit so the scope of the question is narrowed to one topic.  Also, if it is the second, you may wish to have a look at [these results](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=internet+sharing).  If the former, please add your networking details like IP address settings for each adapter.

Comment: Are you using internet sharing?  I suspect a problem with the ip addresses.

Comment: Thanks @Allan. Clarified per your suggestions. It is definitely the former question. Internet sharing I'm OK with not solving at this moment.  More important to get up and running with debugging scripts on the Pi.

Comment: The best and easiest thing to do is to get your RPi on the same network (subnet) as your WiFi. If you need help with that, you might try posting a question on [RPi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). Be sure to include particulars on your RPi, and some basic information on your WiFi network.